# Extract a number from a string in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

Suppose I have a string of this form

```
this is a sentence 234225, and some 857307 other stuff, Time=72625, other stuff
```

what is the fastest way to extrapolate number 72625 in Python?

Comment: @RikPoggi Unfortunately I think this is a common "stumper" for people learning Python -- it's often the first thing they need an `import` for, so they don't even know where to start.

Comment: why so much disappointment btw?

Comment: @Bob People don't like it when you ask an "easy" question without showing what you tried yourself or explaining where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: @agf: Than that someone should ask: "I don't know where to start, pointers?". Not "What is the fastest way?".

Comment: @RikPoggi I agree he should have shown more effort. I just give people a little more leeway on certain topics.

Comment: @agf: This way you're not much helping them. The whole point of being here is not to provide copy and paste answer for in their code, but to learn something. Someone that doesn't know how to `import` needs a tutorial not `re.findall`.

Comment: @RikPoggi But at least now they know they need to look up `import` and `re`.

Comment: Bob, remember to accept answers to your questions. I notice many of your questions with good answers don't have one marked as accepted.

Comment: The real problem with the question is you haven't said what distinguishes the 62625.  Are you looking for the 3rd integer on the line, or any integer after an =, or after Time=?

Comment: possible duplicate of [extracting numbers in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867457/extracting-numbers-in-a-string)

Answer (score 10):

Using [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) gets you the simplest output, and works for any number of matches.

```
sent = "this is a sentence 234225, and some 857307 other stuff, Time=72625, other stuff"

import re

print re.findall("Time=(\d+)", sent)
# ['72625']
```

Answer (score 3):

If

```
>>> st="this is a sentence 234225, and some 857307 other stuff, Time=72625, other stuff"
```

another way of doing it without regex is

```
>>> st.split("Time=")[-1].split()[0]
'72625'
>>>
```

Comment: He only wants to match numbers after `Time=` otherwise he would have asked how to match all three not just `72625`.

Comment: How do you know it will always have a comma after it? How do you know there will only be one place that matches? That's the advantage of regular expressions in cases like this.

Comment: @agf: I have removed the comma and the result remains the same. I am never disagreeing with the power of regex but its not wrong to figure out alternate better ways if it works :-)

Comment: The result doesn't remain the same, now the result is `'72625,'`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
input = "this is a sentence 234225, and some 857307 other stuff, Time=72625, other stuff"
print re.search('Time=(\d+)', input).group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> x = 'this is a sentence 234225, and some 857307 other stuff, Time=72625, other stuff'
>>> re.search('(?<=Time=)\d+',x).group()
'72625'
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

Comment: Don't post just a link as an answer. Show how to use the linked material to solve the problem.

Comment: Well i feel there shouldn't have been any link. Would be best answer for this type of question..